# Internet Explorer not playing html 5 videos after playing 50 videos

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video

I have an eLearning course with 120 1 to 3 minute videos with autoplay and preload="auto".

It's packaged in SCORM 1.2 and hosted on CornerStone.

After viewing +-40 videos, the videos won't playing, showing only a Blank Screen Internet Explorer 11.

Instructing the video to play with javascript doesn't make it play.

Viewing the video readyState returns 0.

Viewing the IE Network Analysis shows that videos have a 206 or 304 error.

If I exit the course and re-enter it, it will return me to where I was at and it will start playing videos normally.

What is happening and what can I do to fix this issue?

Edit: The issue seems to be due to some bug on IE h264 codecs. A video might play well, and on second viewing it will give a "Error reading codec" message when activating controls.

Comment: I suggest you try to make this test on multiple machines. It can help you to know whether it is the issue with a specific machine or it can happen with any machine. If the site is available publicly then you can share the link for the test. Let us know, which OS you are using for this test? Try to check for the latest updates, install it and make a test with it. Low hardware configuration can also be the reason for this issue or it can possible that IE meets with any limitation cause this issue.

Comment: This has been happenning on multiple PCs, Windows 10 with IE11 (both latest).
Although it happens to every machine we tried, lower end machines are more likely to have this issue.

Comment: We don't know, what code your site uses to load and play these videos. There is no code sample to produce the issue. So we can't say whether this issue can be fixed by optimizing the code. In that case, you can try to check and find the IE browser using JS and try to take further steps to avoid the issue.

Comment: Pure video html5 with html pages loaded via jquery.
This seems to be a IE BUG.

Comment: Without checking the code, we can't say that it is an IE browser issue. If you need to confirm. I suggest you post a sample code to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a memory leak or other bug in IE's implementation of HTML 5 video. The 206 and 304 codes are a red herring; neither is an error (304 happens any time the browser already has something cached -  the server tells the browser "you've already got the latest version" with a 304 code - and 206 codes are common when loading video: it's the server saying "here's part of the response so you can start playing it, and there will be more").

If this is indeed a memory leak (or some other IE-specific problem), your solution needs to work around it. You could reload the browser window after every 30 videos (or some number that makes sense); if you were to do that, you could keep track of which video was last played on the URL - which, actually, might be a good thing to do anyway (in case the user reloads the page thinking the browser would "remember" what their last video was).

How easy or difficult it would be on page-load to conditionally load a specified video would depend on your implementation.  But you'd keep track of most-recent-video on the URL either like `#lastVidId=1224` (programmatically changing the hash by setting `location.href` whenever a new video loads), or like `?lastVidId=1234` (programmatically changing the URL without reloading the page using either `pushState()` or `replaceState()` (probably the latter in your case).

Hope this helps; I think this is a problem to work around, not to tackle head-on, especially since it involves an old browser like IE.

Comment: The course already memorizes the user placement. For now we are incentivizing people not to use IE, and if they do use, to refresh the page in case the videos break.